# How to mimic an ON condition while using Union?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a query like this:

```
select
    yyyy_mm_dd,
    xml_id,
    feature,
    status
from
    schema.t1
where
    yyyy_mm_dd >= '2019-02-02'

union all

select
    yyyy_mm_dd,
    p_id as xml_id,
    'payment' as feature,
    case
        when payment = 1 then 1
        else 0
    end as status
from
    schema.t2
where
    yyyy_mm_dd >= '2019-02-02'
```

Is there a way I can ensure no side of the `union` has a greater date than the other? With a join I could enforce this with an `on` condition on `yyyy_mm_dd`. I want to maintain the union but only until the max date which is available in *both* tables.

---

Is there a more efficient way to solve this than the solution I've come up with?

```
select
    c.yyyy_mm_dd,
    xml_id,
    feature,
    status
from
    schema.t1 c
left join(
    select
        max(yyyy_mm_dd) as yyyy_mm_dd
    from
        schema.t2
    where
        yyyy_mm_dd >= '2020-10-01'
) m on m.yyyy_mm_dd = c.yyyy_mm_dd
where
    c.yyyy_mm_dd >= '2020-10-01'
    and m.yyyy_mm_dd is null
    
union all

select
    c.yyyy_mm_dd,
    p_id as xml_id,
    'payment' as feature,
    case
        when payment = 1 then 1
        else 0
    end as status
from
    schema.t2 c
left join(
    select
        max(yyyy_mm_dd) as yyyy_mm_dd
    from
        schema.t1
    where
        yyyy_mm_dd >= '2020-10-01'
) m on m.yyyy_mm_dd = c.yyyy_mm_dd

where
    c.yyyy_mm_dd >= '2020-10-01'
    and m.yyyy_mm_dd is not null
```

Comment: The solution with the left joins, does not only apply the condition that you want but it also filters out any uncommon dates. Is this that you want?

Comment: Yes, I would like to the `union` to output data for `yyyy_mm_dd` rows which are present in both tables. So if t1 has data up until `2020-10-06` and t2 only has data up until `2020-10-04`, then I want the solution to return all rows up until `2020-10-04` as that is the point where data stops being available in t2.I also want this to work the other way (vice versa)

Comment: So you want only the matching dates of both queries.

Comment: Pretty much. Similar to `inner join t2 on t2.yyyy_mm_dd = t1.yyyy_mm_dd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 [`CTE`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression)s for each of your queries and then select only the rows of each CTE that have matching `yyyy_mm_dd`s in the other CTE:

```
with 
  cte1 as (
    select yyyy_mm_dd, xml_id, feature, status
    from schema.t1
    where yyyy_mm_dd >= '2019-02-02'
  ),
  cte2 as (
    select yyyy_mm_dd,  p_id as xml_id, 'payment' as feature,
           case when payment = 1 then 1 else 0 end as status
    from schema.t2
    where yyyy_mm_dd >= '2019-02-02'
  )
select c1.* from cte1 c1
where exists (select 1 from cte2 c2 where c2.yyyy_mm_dd = c1.yyyy_mm_dd)
union all
select c2.* from cte2 c2
where exists (select 1 from cte1 c1 where c1.yyyy_mm_dd = c2.yyyy_mm_dd)
```

Comment: Very nice, works great. Never used a `CTE` before. One small error in the solution, you need to alias `cte2` as `c2` so the query will run.

Comment: @Someguywhocodes correct, I edited, copy/paste issues.

Comment: My original query is a subquery in a larger `SELECT`. It seems the `CTE` solution unfortunately doesn't work as a subquery and throws this - `Failed to recognize predicate 'select'. Failed rule: 'queryStatementExpression' in subquery source`. The query looks like `select x.* from( with cte1 as ( ... ) , cte2 as (...) ... ) x`

Comment: You can have the ctes before `select x.* from...`.